# Reverse date format within various templates methods

Tags: xml, xslt

Main goal - to revert format of all dates which are tied with different transformation methods (here 3 of them). 2 of 3 nodes with date (parent and child-1) can be changed by the submitted date-reverting template, and the last one - can't (child-2).

The structure of the child-2 XSLT-template have to stay the same ( or maybe not if its goal will be taken into account). The goal(s) of this node transformation is to change attributes' names in this node and the date's attribute name have to be renamed also (along with reverting) .

How to improve XSLT code to  get all 3 dates changed? [with XSLT 1.0]

**SOURCE**

```
<root>
  <parent attr-1="some value" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="10.11.2017">
    <child attr-2="some value-2" DateAttributeChild-1="09.12.2010"> </child>
    <child-2 attr-3="some value-3" DateAttributeChild-2="05.11.2007"> </child-2>
  </parent> 
</root>
```

**XSLT transform**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity transform -->

  <xsl:template match="@DateAttributeParent | @DateAttributeChild-1 | @DateAttributeChild-2">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
      <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
      <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- parent  template -->
  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <parent>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </parent>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- child-1 template -->

  <xsl:template match="child-1">
    <child-1>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" >
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </child-1>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- child-2 template -->
<xsl:template match="child-2">
  <child-2>
      <xsl:attribute name="attr-3renamed">
        <xsl:value-of select="@attr-3"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

<xsl:attribute name="NonRevertingDate">
  <xsl:value-of select="@DateAttributeChild-2"/>
</xsl:attribute>
    </child-2>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<root>
  <parent attr-1="some value" attr-2="abc" DateAttributeParent="2017.11.10">
    <child attr-2="some value-2" DateAttributeChild-1="2010.12.09"> </child>
    <child-2 attr-3renamed="some value-3" NonRevertingDate="05.11.2007" /> <!-- didn't revert! -->
  </parent> 
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rename the `DateAttributeChild-2` attribute, then you cannot use the same template you use for the other date attributes, because that template preserves the original name:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
```

In order to avoid code duplication, I would suggest you do the date format conversion in a named template that can be called as needed. Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- reformat some date attributes -->
<xsl:template match="@DateAttributeParent | @DateAttributeChild-1">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:call-template name="reformat-date">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- child-2 template -->
<xsl:template match="child-2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="attr-3renamed">
            <xsl:value-of select="@attr-3"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="NonRevertingDate">
            <xsl:call-template name="reformat-date">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="@DateAttributeChild-2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="reformat-date">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '.'), '.')"/>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '.'), '.')"/>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($date, '.')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note:

- I have removed your "parent  template" because it doesn't do anything that the *identity transform* template doesn't do already.
- I have removed your "child-1 template" because I don't see a `child-1` element in the input.